# Making a list of months and years from DatetimeIndex in Pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, strftime

I have a dataframe of information. I set the index to be the received date and time. Now I want a list

I set the df index doing this:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

which gives me this:

```
print df.index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-07-28 09:42:08, ..., 2015-07-28 09:06:12]
Length: 15177, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

I want a list of the month and years in order to use them to plot, like so: `["Jan 2015", "Feb 2015", "Mar 2015", "Apr 2015", "May 2015", "June 2015", "Jul 2015", "Aug 2014", "Sep 2014", "Oct 2014", "Nov 2014", "Dec 2014"]`

How can I do this? I've looked into something like this:

```
df = [datetime.datetime.strftime(n,'%b-%Y') for n in pd.DataFrame(df).resample('M').index]
```

But this gives me the error `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`.

Comment: But do you really want a *list* of datetimes? I suspect you want a pandas DatetimeIndex, or Series, esp. if it's for slicing your index with `.loc[]` When you say *"in order to use them to plot"*, I suspect you want the actual datetimes to make the slice with `.loc[]`, not just the string labels for the plot's time-axis.

Answer (score 15):

#### Original answer

The following should work: convert your datetimeindex to a [series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_series.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_series), so you can call `apply` and use [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to return an array of strings:

```
In [27]:
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start = dt.datetime(2014,1,1), end = dt.datetime.now(), freq='M'))
df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%b %Y'))

Out[27]:
2014-01-31    Jan 2014
2014-02-28    Feb 2014
2014-03-31    Mar 2014
2014-04-30    Apr 2014
2014-05-31    May 2014
2014-06-30    Jun 2014
2014-07-31    Jul 2014
2014-08-31    Aug 2014
2014-09-30    Sep 2014
2014-10-31    Oct 2014
2014-11-30    Nov 2014
2014-12-31    Dec 2014
2015-01-31    Jan 2015
2015-02-28    Feb 2015
2015-03-31    Mar 2015
2015-04-30    Apr 2015
2015-05-31    May 2015
2015-06-30    Jun 2015
Freq: M, dtype: object
```

If you want a list then just call `tolist()`:

```
df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%b %Y')).tolist()
```

---

#### Updated answer

Actually, looking at this question 2 years later, I realise the above is completely unnecessary. You can just do:

```
In [10]:
df.index.strftime('%Y-%b')

Out[10]:
array(['2014-Jan', '2014-Feb', '2014-Mar', '2014-Apr', '2014-May',
       '2014-Jun', '2014-Jul', '2014-Aug', '2014-Sep', '2014-Oct',
       '2014-Nov', '2014-Dec', '2015-Jan', '2015-Feb', '2015-Mar',
       '2015-Apr', '2015-May', '2015-Jun', '2015-Jul', '2015-Aug',
       '2015-Sep', '2015-Oct', '2015-Nov', '2015-Dec', '2016-Jan',
       '2016-Feb', '2016-Mar', '2016-Apr', '2016-May', '2016-Jun',
       '2016-Jul', '2016-Aug', '2016-Sep', '2016-Oct', '2016-Nov',
       '2016-Dec', '2017-Jan', '2017-Feb', '2017-Mar', '2017-Apr',
       '2017-May', '2017-Jun', '2017-Jul'], 
      dtype='<U8')
```

`datetimeindex` support `.dt` accessors directly without converting to a `Series`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do this as of pandas 1.0.x (2020). You can generate arbitrary [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with arbitrary frequency, then [`strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) it into arbitrary format. All in one line:

```
>>> pd.date_range(start='7/2019', end='6/2020', freq='M').strftime('%Y-%b')
Index(['2019-Jul', '2019-Aug', '2019-Sep', '2019-Oct', '2019-Nov', '2019-Dec',
       '2020-Jan', '2020-Feb', '2020-Mar', '2020-Apr', '2020-May'],
      dtype='object')
```