# How do you copy monthly columns from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a dataframe taking the months from the current year plus the months from the previous year to make 12. Also am getting rid of  rows so taking it row-by-row to check and get rid of garbage rows.

The two Excel sheets have been imported to dataframes:

#### Input: df_ExcelSheet2019

```
           jan-19  feb-19  mar-19  apr-19  may-19  ...  sep-19  oct-19  nov-19  dec-19
row_name 1    0.1    0.12    0.55    0.54    0.44  ...    0.72    0.44    0.37    0.55
row_name 2    0.2    0.24    0.22    0.55    0.41  ...    0.66    0.15    0.51    0.42
row_name 3    0.3    0.54    0.65    0.32    0.38  ...    0.33    0.66    0.89    0.74
<garbage>
row_name 5    0.4    0.53    0.17    0.53    0.81  ...    0.73    0.44    0.16    0.21
row_name 6    0.5    0.55    0.75    0.83    0.48  ...    0.68    0.16    0.57    0.11
```

#### Input: df_ExcelSheet2020

```
           jan-20  feb-20  mar-20  apr-20  may-20  ...  sep-20  oct-20  nov-20  dec-20
row_name 1    0.1    0.12    0.55    0.54    0.44  ...    0.72    0.44    0.37    0.55
row_name 2    0.2    0.24    0.22    0.55    0.41  ...    0.66    0.15    0.51    0.42
row_name 3    0.3    0.54    0.65    0.32    0.38  ...    0.33    0.66    0.89    0.74
<garbage>
row_name 5    0.4    0.53    0.17    0.53    0.81  ...    0.73    0.44    0.16    0.21
row_name 6    0.5    0.55    0.75    0.83    0.48  ...    0.68    0.16    0.57    0.11
```

#### Desired result:

`df_final` (Ex. first 6 months from 2020 and last 6 months from 2019)

```
           jun-19  jul-19  aug-19  sep-19  oct-19  ...  feb-20  mar-20  apr-20  may-20
row_name 1    0.51   0.65    0.42    0.72    0.44  ...    0.12    0.55    0.54    0.44
row_name 2    0.32   0.78    0.61    0.66    0.15  ...    0.24    0.22    0.55    0.41
row_name 3    0.53   0.11    0.45    0.33    0.66  ...    0.54    0.65    0.32    0.38
row_name 4    0.74   0.12    0.68    0.73    0.44  ...    0.53    0.17    0.53    0.81
row_name 5    0.57   0.23    0.56    0.68    0.16  ...    0.55    0.75    0.83    0.48
```

#### Code:

```
row_data = []
#col - is an offset declared above based the Excel sheet structure
#currentYearFormat - a list of rows I want, garbage rows removed

for item in currentYearFormat:
    row = item[2] - 2 # 1 for 1to0 conversion and 1 because pandas ignores blank rows
    print("row: ",row)
    
    #copy elements from Previous sheet
    row_data = [df_previousYearOIR.iloc[row,col-previousYearMonths+12:col+12]]
    print("row name: " item[0])
    print("previous: \n", row_data)
    print("\n")
    #take elements from Current sheet and extend row_data
    row_data += [df_currentYearOIR.iloc[row,col:col+currentYearMonths]]
    print("extended: \n", row_data)
```

#### Current result:

```
row: 2
row name: row_name 1
previous: 
 [Unnamed: 18    0.31
Unnamed: 19    0.38
Unnamed: 20    0.43
Unnamed: 21    0.72
Unnamed: 22    0.44
Unnamed: 23    0.37
Unnamed: 24    0.55
Name: 2, dtype: object]


extended: 
 [Unnamed: 18    0.31
Unnamed: 19    0.38
Unnamed: 20    0.43
Unnamed: 21    0.72
Unnamed: 22    0.44
Unnamed: 23    0.37
Unnamed: 24    0.55
Name: 2, dtype: object, Unnamed: 13     0.5
Unnamed: 14    0.1
Unnamed: 15    0.12
Unnamed: 16    0.55
Unnamed: 17    0.54
Name: 2, dtype: object]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. _I want to create a dataframe taking the months from the current year plus the months from the previous year to make 12._ Can you expand on that? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ex - I want last 6 months data (Jul-Dec) from a data frame with last year's data and the 1st 6 months of data from this year's dataframe (Jan-Jun). I want to put that data into a new dataframe. I need to grab the data row by row (vs enmass) to remove garbage rows.

Comment: @kalmdown You could select the desired columns from 2019 df and the 2020 df and then remove the garbage rows in each dfs and then conact these 2 data frames. Or remove the garbage rows after joining the selected columns from 2019 df and 2020 df.

Comment: Your monthly data is actually in ***columns***, not rows. So really you want to slice the ***columns*** Jan-Jun 2020 and concatenate them column-wise `pd.concat(..., axis=1)` it to Jul-Dec 2019.

Comment: I edited the title to help, but please edit it yourself if you can improve on that

Comment: @kalmdown  That is still not a [mcve]. Also, please share the data in more convenient format.

Comment: Related: [Making a list of months and years from DatetimeIndex in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710454/making-a-list-of-months-and-years-from-datetimeindex-in-pandas/62628529#62628529)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can [accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on the big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can also upvote answers by clicking on the upper gray triangle.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354584/teaching-new-users-how-to-accept-an-answer). You've only accepted answers on [2 of the 8 questions you've posted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533309/kalmdown)

Answer (score 0):

You could select the desired columns from 2019 df and the 2020 df and then remove the garbage rows in each dfs and then concat these 2 data frames. Or remove the garbage rows after joining the selected columns from 2019 df and 2020 df.

```
current_month = datetime.datetime.today().month
joined_df = pd.concat([df_2019[df_2019.columns[current_month:]], df_2020[df_2020.columns[:current_month]]], axis=1)
```

Once you have this, you can apply the logic to remove garbage, make a boolean mask and eliminate the garbage rows from this joined df.

```
joined_df['garbage'] = <apply some logic to identify garbage rows>
final_df = joined_df[joined_df['garbage']==False]
```

Comment: Hmmm...hadn't thought of that. I'll give it a try and see if I can make that work.

Answer (score 0):

Your monthly data is actually in ***columns***, not rows. So really you want to slice the ***columns*** Jan-Jun 2020 and concatenate them column-wise `pd.concat(..., axis=1)` to the columns for Jul-Dec 2019.

- Or else, and since in general pandas (and most data science tools) do operations far more easily with rows, not columns, it would seriously make things easier if you ***transposed*** your dataframes immediately when you read them in: `pd.read_excel(...).T`. That's `.T` or equivalently the `.transpose()` function. Now each month's data is in ***rows***.
- In fact you could also concat your two dataframes when you read them in:

  `df_all90 = pd.concat([pd.read_excel('<2019.xls>'), pd.read_excel('<2020.xls>')], axis=1).T`
- Now all that's left is to slice your rows of interest:

  `df = df_all90.loc[['jul-19','aug-19',...,'dec-19','jan-20',...,'jun-20']]`
  or `df.iloc[i:j]` for some pair of integer indices

Note:

- I wrote `...` in that list of labels for `.loc[]`, but you have to manually fill in the whole slice expression with all the months (pandas has some daterange functions but let's just keep this simple).
- pandas can exactly a range of DatetimeIndex in the exact strftime format you want (you could then use this as the `.iloc[]` slice expression).

Code:

```
>>> pd.date_range(start='7/2019', end='6/2020', freq='M').strftime('%Y-%b')

Index(['2019-Jul', '2019-Aug', '2019-Sep', '2019-Oct', '2019-Nov', '2019-Dec',
       '2020-Jan', '2020-Feb', '2020-Mar', '2020-Apr', '2020-May'],
      dtype='object')
```

- [`pd.DatetimeIndex` actually supports an `indexer_between_time(self, start_time, end_time...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time.html) comparison operator, but apparently only for times not for dates or datetimes. So could slice your df between start..end dates.

Comment: Another very different approach. I may have to try both of these as a learning experience. Thanks.

Comment: kalmdowm: sure, give all these a try, let me know if anything needs better explanation

Comment: The problem ends up being that the Excel spreadsheet has two sets of data. A set, in the 1st 12 columns and a set in the next 12 columns, but each set uses rows differently. I guess I could extract each column separately and transpose that set in its own dataframe. Probably look for other solutions first but will keep this in mind.

Comment: kalmdown: So just `pd.read_excel()` both files separately, fix their rows/columns up, then `pd.concat([...])` them, like I'm showing here. This is your solution.